# How to reuse an Index that already created using Apache Lucene?

Tags: apache, text-processing, indexing, lucene, solr

I have a program using Lucene that create index in a Directory (index directory) every time. As everyone knows that creating index on each and every execution  is time consuming process , I want to reuse the already created index in the initial execution ?

IS it possible in Lucene . Do Lucene have this feature ?

Comment: Is there something about `IndexSearcher` that's inadequate for your application?

Comment: I'm guessing you open a new IndexWriter with the improper OpenMode (you set it to "create") and that erases your existing index? Try configuring it with OpenMOode.APPEND or CREATE_OR_APPEND: http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.html

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible. Assuming `indexDirPath` is the location of your lucene index, you can use the following code:

```
Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDirPath));
IndexReader ir = DirectoryReader.open(dir);

IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(ir);
```

This should be followed by use of the appropriate Analyzer you used while creating the index.